# What are the definitions of runtime limits and compile time limits?

Tags: c, linux, limit

From [APUE](https://books.google.com/books?id=_kpsAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA37&ots=Fawy3-NZL_&dq=if%20a%20particular%20runtime%20limit%20does%20not%20vary%20on%20a%20given%20system%2C%20it%20can%20be%20de%EF%AC%81ned%20statically%20in%20a%20header&pg=PA36#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> Many of these have been hard coded into programs or were determined
>   using ad hoc techniques. With the various standardization efforts that
>   we’ve described, more portable methods are now provided to determine
>   these magic numbers and implementation-deﬁned limits, greatly
>   improving the portability of software written for the UNIX
>   environment.
>
> Two types of limits are needed:
>
> 1. Compile-time limits (e.g., what’s the largest value of a short integer?)
> 2. Runtime limits (e.g., how many bytes in a ﬁlename?)
>
> **Compile-time limits can be deﬁned in headers** that any program can include at compile time.  But **runtime limits require the process to
>   call a function to obtain the limit’s value.**
>
> ...
>
> To further confuse things, **if a particular runtime limit does not
>   vary on a given system, it  can  be  deﬁned  statically  in  a 
>   header.** If it is not  deﬁned  in  a  header, however, the
>   application  must  call  one  of  the  three conf functions  (which 
>   we  describe  shortly)  to determine its value at runtime.

At first, it seems to me that compile-time limits are defined as those which can be defined in headers, and runtime limits are defined as those which cannot.

Then it seems to me that a runtime limit can be defined in a header too.

So what are the definitions of runtime limits and compile time limits?

Answer (score 3):

Your original definition is already correct. If you are able to use an accurate limit from a header, then it implies that for that system, it's a compile-time limit. It could be a run-time limit on some other system, in which case the header wouldn't provide a static definition.

Alternatively, you could think of anything for which a function exists as a run-time limit; sure, it's actually a constant value on some systems, but for portable code you'd need to use the function anyway, so it's a run-time limit that just happens to be really cheap to check on some systems (where the function can be defined to return the static value).

Point is, there isn't one exact answer; some things are conditionally run-time or compile-time depending on the system, some things are always compile-time, some things are always run-time. It's a Venn Diagram.

Comment: Thanks. (1) do you mean a limit can be both a compile time limit in a system, and a runtime limit on another system? (2) Do you mean that on a system, a limit may be provided in a header file, but it is not accurate, and to get an accurate limit, we must call a function, so in this case the limit is actually a runtime limit not a compile time limit?

Comment: @Tim: 1: Yes. 2. Yes (e.g. some `sysconf` values with definitions in the header are guaranteed minimums, but actually calling `sysconf` might reveal a higher value). `sysconf`'s man page is a good example of this mixed setup; the constant limits aren't guaranteed to be defined, so when they're not available you need to use `sysconf` for a run-time value. If the header defines it, that limit should *work*, but run-time querying might let your code perform better using the higher run-time determined limit.

Answer (score 2):

The runtime limit, of say a full pathname may well depend on the version of the operating system.

If you want your program to be able to run on an old system with shorter path name limits(say 128 characters), you would not want it to artificially limited on newer systems with much larger limits (say 4096) characters.

The only way to get best behaviour is to make a system call to determine the current limit, or to adapt your code so that it can cope with longer strings if it encounters them, and properly reports system errors if too-long paths are passed to older systems.

As PJ says, you need some flexibility anyway if you have different file systems attached that impose their own limits that you also need to handle gracefully, but they are often inside a whole-system imposed limit.

To some extent, if you are using high level languages with dynamic string lengths and such, you are insulated from these runtime limits, but it is useful to understand that they do exist.

Answer (score 1):

@Tim not. Imagine that you have system which may have many file devices attached. Any of those may have own different limits. It can be only discovered runtime as compile time you do not know what hardware will be used.